# How to fix textContent as undefined inside of for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, undefined

When i run the code below, it says "Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined". Even onclick, addEventListener, length and much more says undefined! How can i fix this?

Here's the code:

```
<div id = "dropdown-content" class = "d-con">
    <a href = "#">America</a>
    <a href = "#">Canada</a>
    <a href = "#">Rio</a>
</div>
```

And The javaScript:

```
(function(){
    var i;
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('d-con');
    for(i = 0; i <= dropdown.length; i = i + 1){
        alert(dropdown[i].textContent);
    }
}());
```

Comment: For this, i have kept script at last of body and yet doesn't work :( Do you have other solution?

Comment: @AndrewLi No it's not a synchronisation problem, it's rather a problem in the for loop.

Comment: @chsdk Oh duh, I didn't check that -- classic off by one error.

Comment: Yeah Got The Answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only problem here is that your `i` counter reaches `dropdown.length` and `dropdown[dropdown.length]` is `undefined`, in other words you are trying to access an `undefined` element in the `dropdown` array.

That's why your code alerts the first 3 elements then throws the error, when it tries to access this `undefined` element.

**Solution:**

In the `for` loop your condition should be `i < dropdown.length` and not `i <= dropdown.length`.

```
(function() {
  var i;
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('d-con');
  for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    alert(dropdown[i].textContent);
  }
}());
```

**Demo:**

```js
(function() {
  var i;
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('d-con');
  for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    alert(dropdown[i].textContent);
  }
}());
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-content" class="d-con">
  <a href="#">America</a>
  <a href="#">Canada</a>
  <a href="#">Rio</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much! Looks like I have to gather more common sense in my mind! Thanks a lot! Woooooohh!

Comment: @Bill You are welcome ;) It's just a question of attention.

Answer (score 1):

Here try to check this code.

No need to make a loop for inner elements.

```js
(function(){
        var i;
        var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('d-con');
        alert(dropdown[0].textContent);
    }());
```

```html
<div id = "dropdown-content" class = "d-con">
        <a href="#">America</a>
        <a href="#">Canada</a>
        <a href="#">Rio</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check this

```
    (function(){
      $('.d-con a').each(function(key, value){
        console.log(value.textContent);
      });
    }());
```

Answer (score 0):

If `div` with id `dropdown-content` is the only element that contains class `d-con`, then grab the element by using `getElementById` or you can simply alert the content without using any loop by writing `alert(dropdown[0].textContent);`